# Before Delete Flow Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am performing related records update in before delete flow salesforce, curious to know if the record which triggered this flow, failed to be deleted due to any reason, what will happen to the related records? Will they be rolled back or will be committed?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the execution of the flow fails at some point, all the additional DMLs performed by the Flow will be **rolled back** (doesn't matter if the changes affect other related records). This is because the Flow runs inside a transaction and it is not until the end of the transaction that the changes in the database are committed to the database. If any unhandled exception are found, the changes on the transaction will be rolled back.

You can check more information here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.process_considerations_transactions.htm&type=5